# I have one custom field in rally, Field name: CSST Test Set Category

Tags: rally

Field name: CSST Test Set Category. The custom field under Test sets, I want query using that custom field to generate custom reports. query: ((CSST Test Set Category).Name = " Prod Cert "), when I try to save the query getting "invalid expression starting at "CSST"". Can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the query should be:

> (c_CSSTTestSetCategory = "Prod Cert")